# How to disable clicking on title bar to restrict minimizing window in windos form application

Tags: winforms

I have developed windows form application. I achieved disabling double clicking on title bar and also hid maximize and minimize buttons.But single clicking and moving cursor causing window to get minimized.Is there any way to restrict minimizing the window by any way.Only close button on title bar should work.

Answer (score 0):

on the form proerpties set controlbox to false and form border style to none, then make your own button to close the window.

If you want the window to be draggable, use this code I found somewhere long ago and cannot recall to give credit.

```
Dim drag As Boolean
Dim mousex As Integer
Dim mousey As Integer

Private Sub mainform_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    drag = True 'Sets the variable drag to true.
    mousex = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left 'Sets variable mousex
    mousey = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top 'Sets variable mousey
End Sub

Private Sub mainform_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    'If drag is set to true then move the form accordingly.
    If drag Then
        Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
        Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - mousex
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub mainform_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    drag = False 'Sets drag to false, so the form does not move according to the code in MouseMove
End Sub
```